# NodeJs | Passing parameters between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a problem with the handling of a json object, I want to send it to another module on function callback but it always returns undefined.

Here is what I have,
upon visiting the page this gets called :

```
var getprofile = require('./../functions/getprofile');
exports.index = function(req, res){
  getprofile.profileFunc(function(profile) {
    res.render('index', profile);   
  });
};
```

Then the profileFunc is called from the getprofile module :

```
var profileFunc = function(callback) {
  var myApi = require('./myApi');
  myApi.user('usernameHere', function(error, profile) {
    callback.apply(null, profile);
  });
};
exports.profileFunc = profileFunc;
```

The problem happens when I want to render, the profile is a JSON object and it tells me that it's undefined after the callback.

Comment: If the `profile` you get from `myApi.user` is the *object* you want, you cannot pass it into `.apply()`. Just call `callback(profile);`.

Comment: Alright now I've got the profile to show when I Console.log before the "res.render" but it still gives me this error when I try to use profile : #{profile.name} Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your view engine, but doesn't that expect a `profile` property on the passed object - how does it know the namespace is called `profile`? Try `#{ name }` instead.

Comment: Found out how to! Thanks alot for your help, I need to use name indeed, but my data went like this data.name instead of name.